# Jquery how to select tag that does not contain two classes?

Tags: jquery

In jquery, how can you select all tags, that doesn't have class `A` and class `B`.

Comment: Do you mean "that doesn't have (class A and class B)", or do you mean "that (doesn't have class A) and (class B)"?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: To clarify Blazemonger's question, is that `!(A || B)` or `!(A && B)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$(':not(.A.B)')
```

to select all elements that dont have both class A and class B.